# Adding *ngFor index value causes 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor, ngx-bootstrap

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryym9l-4rxbl7?file=app%2Fngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts)

I have a fairly simple view that loops over `html` using angular's `*ngFor` hook. I use a [ngx-bootstrap collapse](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/collapse) to show more/less content depending on content `.length`. The issue I was getting is when I collapse one more/less button they all collapse/expand.

I have added `let i - index;` to the `*ngFor` to index each button, adding like such isCollapsed[i]. The index is counting correctly.

In my .ts file I have initialised like `isCollapsed = true;` but get the following error `Cannot create property '1' on boolean 'true'`. I then change this to `isCollapsed: boolean[] = [];` I then get the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Here is a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryym9l-4rxbl7?file=app%2Fngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts) of my applications view - any help or fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize `isCollapsed`.

Just add this:

```
 constructor(){
    this.attributes.map(t=> this.isCollapsed.push(false) );
  }
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryym9l-asennx?file=app%2Fngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts) is working sample.